# Shopify error: connect ETIMEDOUT ipAddress:443 on npm run dev

Tags: npm, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, remix

i just installed shopify cli & remix using npm init @shopify/app@latest, when i run "npm run dev",  it authenticate me and pop up page appeare, successfully selecting shopify partner account, then it throws this error on CMD:

[image]

I used VPN (v2ray), which is essential for my work. I'm not allowed to connect without a VPN at all. Also, I set V2RAY on Global mode!
after that i tried residential proxy (USA locations) instead of v2ray to test if it can fix error but not working.

any suggestions?